# Need to scrape an image in Filemaker from a Web Viewer

Tags: filemaker

I've got my web viewer pointed at a google static map and I'd like to figure out how to save the image file to view later offline.  If you're not familiar, google static map pages are just html pages with single images.  They look like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img... src="">
  </body>
</html>
```

I basically need to either grab the image data from that web viewer to store it, or maybe just scrape the source tag from the HTML to download that somehow.  Anybody have any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of FileMaker are you using? 12 has the new insert from URL script step that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker 12 introduced the Insert from URL command which can be used to grab images.

http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/scripts_ref1.36.46.html

Answer (score 0):

Google images used tiles for the maps, so there's no single URL you can use to retrieve an image of the entire web viewer.

Use ScriptMaster to take a screen capture. You will need to know the coordinates of the web viewer, which you can calculate from the window position and layout element position and size. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the ScriptMaster developers)